# taking marklogic backup using rest api

Tags: shell, marklogic, marklogic-10

```
       #!/bin/bash
       curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X POST -i -d @./bkp.xqy \
       -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-H "Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY" \
http://localhost:8000/v1/eval
```

I m trying above shell script and my bkp.xqy looks like this

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:database-backup(xdmp:database-forests(xdmp:database("Documents")),
"C:\Users\C70945\mlbackup", fn:true(), "C:\Users\C70945\mlbackup", 15)
```

when i run shell i get the below error

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: MarkLogic
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN'>
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You have attempted to access an HTTPS server using HTTP.</p>
</body></html>
```

I am looking for to take a backup using this shell script

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: Addressing the problem(s) above by modifying the answer based on various comments:

First Error:
SSL issues.  from my previous post and contributing comments by various people:

**1. SSL vs non SSL**
That was fixed with:
Change: `http://localhost:8000/v1/eval`
TO: `https://localhost:8000/v1/eval`

**2. Self signed certs**
CuRL does not like that.. (thank's @mads-hansen) This was resolved with the `-k` flag

**3. Now we move onto a new error (see comments) "XDMP-EVALQUERY:"**
This is caused by the script `bkp.xqy` not following the format as documented.  Please see here: https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/eval and specifically the second example.

The request is a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request.  You are actually passing a field in the body that must be named.

Your file needs to start with:
`xquery=` as the first line.

The most simple file I use for testing:

```
xquery=
xquery version "1.0-ml";
1
```

Returns this from the eval endpoint ( "1" being my value from the script):

```
--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Primitive: integer

1
--BOUNDARY--
```

Regarding Your script, there is a management API that can run the backup command for You.  Please see an example here: [KB:Approaches to scripting a database backup using the MarkLogic ReST API](https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/approaches-to-scripting-a-database-backup-using-the-marklogic-rest-api/0)

Comment: hi @David when i change it to https it gives this error - curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Comment: to test, add `-k` to your curl command (it bypasses any certificate validation and checks). You likely are using self-signed certs for the cluster and curl will by default not talk to an endpoint with an untrusted cert.

Comment: OK. to be clear, the original error was answered as mentioned above. Mads has given some sample,guidance related to `-k`. You can also add the verbose and debug flags to get even more insight.  Also, cURL would have listed a URL in its error response (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) as referencd as "visit the web page mentioned above" to help you. Use caution if You have used self signed certs and SSL on the administrative ports to MarkLogic.  With this, You may find yourself with a browser that also does not want to connect by default - thus making administration  a challenge.

Comment: Hi, with -k this time it seems to be working it gives the keep alive message but also it says 400 bad request and the error is : XDMP-EVALQUERY: No query to eval although i have a xquery code in my bkp.xqy code

Comment: @Aviator - This now has 3 parts to the problem as outlined above.  I have re-scripted my answer based on the continued troubleshooting done via comments.  This does, however, make stackOverow messy (title of problem does not match some of the problems).  This is, unfortunately, how Stackoverflow is set up - single problem, single answer.  Strictly speaking, the XDMP-EVALQUERY item warrents a new post (new topic).  For  MarkLogic, it might be good to know that forum posts with a more casual approch to helping eachother can be found here: https://community.progress.com/s/products/marklogic